# Use Variable for Input Instead of File in Bash Script

Tags: bash, unix

I'd like to use "ed" to move lines up and down in linefeed-delimited text held in a variable.  For example, to move line two down:.

input from variable:

```
one
two
three
four
```

output to variable:

```
one
three
two
four
```

The following one-liner works beautifully for a file, but I'd like to feed it a variable.

```
printf '%s\\n' '2,2m3' 'wq' | /bin/ed -s '/inputFile'
```

I've tried assorted variations on

```
printf '%s\\n' '2,2m0' 'wq' | /bin/ed -s <<<$inputVariable
```

which don't work, and my redirection expertise is clearly insufficient to the puzzle.

I'm running macOS 10.15.1.

Comment: Just curious, what is the output of `echo $SHELL`? I don't use Mac, but we did run into another question recently where MacOS was defaulting to `zsh` instead of `bash` which would explain why your *herestring* was not working with a variable.

Comment: The content of here-string is also written to ed's stdin, that might be the problem. I have no experience with ed though

Comment: macOS does indeed default to zsh, but my script is definitely #!/bash .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ed` program process commands from STDIN only (and does not support passing commands via the command line). To make this work, you need to represent the input as a file name (not necessary a file).

The following "convert" the variable `input` to a filename (`/dev/fd/3`) using "here string",

```
#! /bin/bash

input=$(ls -l)
out=$(printf '%s\n' '2,2m3' '1,$p' | ed 3<<<"$input" /dev/fd/3)
echo "$out"
```

Alternatively, with explicit reference to /dev/fd, or to specific file descriptor.

```
#! /bin/bash

input=$(ls -l)
out=$(ed <(printf '%s', "$input") <<___
2,2m3
1,\$p
___
```

Comment: `/proc` isn't universal; I think `/dev/fd/3` is more portable (though it's not universal either). In bash, you could use `ed <(echo "$input")`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson as mentioned in answer, if STDIN is used for the input (variable), there is no way to pass the commands to ed.

Comment: @GordonDavisson On Linux, the '/dev/fd' is symlinked to /proc/self/fd'. If /proc/ not available, than no '/dev/fd'. Also process substitution is (usually) implemented (on Linux) with /dev/fd - same dependency. I've modified the code to use the /dev/fds,

Comment: That's just how Linux does it. OP mentioned that they're running macOS, which doesn't have /proc at all, but has /dev/fd/* (as direct character special devices, not symlinks). I checked a NetBSD system, and it's similar.

Comment: dash-o's 

  out=$(printf '%s\n' '2,2m3' '1,$p' | ed 3<<<"$input" /dev/fd/3) 

works perfectly under Darwin with the addition of -s to suppress diagnostics.

  out=$(printf '%s\n' '2,2m3' '1,$p' | ed -s 3<<<"$input" /dev/fd/3)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Bash's built-in index manipulation rather than spawning ed:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

inputVariable='one
two
three
four
five
six
'

IFS=$'\n' set -- $inputVariable

swp=3 # swap lines 3 and 4

printf '%s\n' "${@:1:swp-1}" "${@:swp+1:1}" "${@:swp:1}" "${@:swp+2}"
```

Output:

```
one
two
four
three
five
six
```

Detail of functions:

- `IFS=$'\n' set -- $inputVariable`: Transfers `$inputVariable`'s lines as arguments.
- `printf '%s\n'`: Prints arguments as lines.
- `"${@:1:swp-1}"`: Expands all arguments lines from 1<sup>st</sup> index to last index before the swap.
- `"${@:swp+1:1}" "${@:swp:1}"`: Performs the actual arguments lines swap, with next index `swp+1` followed by `swp` index.
- `"${@:swp+2}"`: Expands all remaining arguments after the swapped indexes `swp+2`.